# django custom filters not working

Tags: python, django

Here is my folders organization :

[image]

core_extras.py content :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.conf import settings

from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def get_develop_state():
    return settings.DEVELOP

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def in_group(user, group_name):
    group = Group.objects.get(name=group_name)
    return user.groups.filter(name=group_name).exists()

@register.filter
def do_nothing(value):
    return value
```

How I load custom tag/filter in html :

```
{% load i18n staticfiles core_extras %}
{% get_develop_state as DEVELOP %}
```

How I use my tag/filter :

```
{% if DEVELOP or request.user|in_group:"testers" %}
```

The `get_develop_state` is working correctly, but for my filter `in_group`, I got the error `Invalid filter: 'in_group'`.

The application `core` is in my `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Why is my filter not registered ?

Comment: A person with 495 reps really ought to know better than to post screenshots of the code instead of the code itself.

Comment: genuine question, why is that bad ? Because you can't copy/paste ? I'll update it.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: Thanks for the precision, it makes sense !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm stupid.

I loaded `{% load i18n staticfiles core_extras %}` in a base html file which I extend then on child html files. The `get_develop_state` was working because I import it as a variable `DEVELOP` which is available on the child html files but not the filter `in_group`. I just loaded `{% load in_group %}` in the child html and everything works...